# How can I set a link for each word in a sentence?

Tags: javascript

The best way to explain my question is using the example:

https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/casa

As you hover each word within the main content, it refers to a link for the meaning of the "hovered" word. Is it possible to configure each word to turn into a link, and refer all links to its "meaning"?

I believe that a function that turns all words into links to its "pages" would be ok.

This is what we've been trying:

```
var link = /wordToReplace/gi;
var urlLink = 'https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/wordToBeReplaced';
var newLink = urlLink.replace(wordToBeReplaced, 'wordToReplace');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a function that upon hover of each element with a particular class would then see the html content inside the tag and then search for the definition attaching an additional class that would display a info-layer with the content your JS would inject (the meaning of the word).

- I would start writing with some pseudo-code in order to determine all the steps that your JS script would need to do to achieve this.
- I would then design the HTML so that each word has a span tag with the same class as what the JS will be looking for in order to trigger this function. You can write a separate JS function to split a paragraph into an array and then append the span tag on each array value before placing the array content back into the page.
- Once you have your HTML, I would write your hover function following your pseudo-code you wrote before.
- Finally I would style the code that JS is injecting into the DOM with CSS to finish.

If you are fairly good with jQuery, you can have this done in a few hours, but personally I would just use vanilla JavaScript since this seems like a learning experience for you but it would take longer.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the example below?

```js
var textToConvert = 'Words to be converted to links';
var lookupUrl = 'http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/';

var convertedText = textToConvert.replace(
  /(\w+)/g, 
  '<a href="' + lookupUrl + '$1">$1</a>'
);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = convertedText;
console.log(convertedText);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```